# Rol de sesion Admin y Usuario

Tags: php, mysqli, sesiones, users-roles

Buen día, estimad@s.

Tengo un código ya construido previamente pero no sé de qué forma puedo integrar el inicio de sesión dirigido al:

Panel_Administrador,
Panel_Usuario,
Panel_Externo.

Y que a su vez pueda validar los campos si se teclea algún dato incorrecto, donde de momento solo tengo 2 campos.
Estuve buscando en otras respuestas pero como tal no encontré alguna similar a mi duda.

Por último ¿Es recomendable usar PHP_SELF o generar un archivo entrar.php? Mas que nada para darle seguridad al login y un CRUD.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
header("location: welcome.php");
exit;
}

require_once "config.php";

$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
    $username_err = "Por favor, escribe tu Usuario";
} else{
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
}

if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
    $password_err = "Por favor, escribe tu Contraseña";
} else{
    $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
}

if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){

    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password, usertype FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
        $param_username = $username;
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password, $usertype);
                if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                    if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                        @session_start();           
                        $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                        $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
                        $_SESSION["usertype"] = $usertype;
                        //header("location: welcome.php");
                        $location = "Welcome.php";
                        
                        if($usertype=="admin"){
                            $location="Panel_Administrador.php";
                        }
                        if($usertype=="usuario"){
                            $location="Panel_Usuario.php";
                        }
                        if($usertype=="externo"){
                            $location="Panel_Externo.php";
                        }
                    } else{
                        $password_err = "La contraseña es incorrecta. Por favor, intenta de nuevo.";
                    }
                }
            } else{
                $username_err = "No existe el nombre de usuario. Por favor, contacta al área de Servicios para crear tu Usuario.";
            }
        } else{
            echo "Algo salió mal, por favor vuelve a intentarlo.";
        }
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Porque tienes @ antes de `session_start()`? Bueno, sí sé que es para ocultar errores, pero esa práctica genera más problemas que soluciones. La sesión solo debe inicializarse una vez y antes de cualquier salida. Te sugiero colocarla dentro de _config.php_ porque supongo que lo incluyes en todos tus scripts y, por supuesto, incluirlo antes de realizar cualquier otra cosa.

Comment: En la consulta solo obtienes datos básicos `SELECT id, username, password FROM users`, supongo que tienes un campo para identificar el rol de usuario, inclúyelo en la consulta y, cuando se ingresen datos correctos, analiza el valor para redirigir a donde corresponda.

Comment: Planeas dejar de usar welcome.php como la pagina inicial y cambiar una especifica por cada tipo de usuario, o simplemente redirigir a una pagina especifica despues del login solamente?

Comment: @F.Igor Así es, pretendo que por cada tipo de usuario los envíe a su respectivo panel.

Comment: Hola está haciendo bind_param antes de haber asignado el parámetro. La linea `$param_username = $username;` debe ir antes de la línea `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);` la consulta va a fallar siempre en la forma en que está escrito.

Answer (score 0):

Basandose en la consulta que utilizas, debe existir algun atributo adicional que indique el tipo de usuario que es, debes ajustar la consulta para obtenerlo (aqui suponiendo que `usertype` es un campo de `user`):

```
$sql = "SELECT id, username, password, usertype FROM users WHERE username = ?";
```

Luego al momento de obtener los datos agregar una variable para el tipo:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password, $usertype);
```

Y finalmente al momento de redirigir, usar este valor para decidir la redireccion:

```
$location="welcome.php";

if ($usertype=="admin"){
   $location="Panel_Administrador.php";
}
// otras opciones ...

//Redirige al usuario a la pagina seleccionada
header("location: $location");
```

Puedes hacerlo mas global y crear una funcion que se base en un valor de sesion (que se guarda en conjunto con el resto), por ejemplo:

```
$_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
$_SESSION["id"] = $id;
$_SESSION["username"] = $username;
$_SESSION["usertype"]=$usertype;
```

Y luego ajustar el codigo

```
$location="welcome.php";
if ($_SESSION["usertype"]=="admin"){
   $location="Panel_Administrador.php";
}
// otras opciones ...
//Redirige al usuario a la pagina seleccionada
header("location: $location");
```

Y usar este codigo al inicio de cualquier pagina que desees redirigir. Tambien lo puedes convertir en una funcion que puedes reutilizar en cualquier pagina que desees redirigir a la pagina de usuario, incluso esta misma, por ejemplo:

```
<?php 
     session_start();
     if(isset($_SESSION["usertype"]) && $_SESSION["usertype"] !== ""){
         redirectUser();
     }
```

Comment: Me gustó tu respuesta, sólo me gustaría saber cómo eliminar el `header(location: welcome.php");` para que solo desde el **login** dirija a cada __tipo de usuario__ a su respectivo __Panel__

Comment: @AloneWolf Agregué algunas ideas mas implementar esta redireccion de manera mas generica y reutilizable

Comment: Hice actualización del código con tus consejos, ya cuando hago pruebas me sale el error _Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\intranet\conectar.php on line 70_, en esta linea `mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);`